# Este é um exemplo correto de herança em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Estou estudando formas de aplicar Orientação a Objeto em JavaScript.
Encontrei uma solução para utilizar herança. Gostaria de saber se existem melhores maneiras e como encapsular minhas classes.

O que eu tenho feito:

```
People = function(name){
 this.name = name
 this.age = null; 
};

Employee = function(name){
 People.call(this,name);
 this.IdentificationCode = null;
 this.salary = null;
}

Jonh = new Employee("Jonh Smith");
Jonh.age = 25;
Jonh.IdentificationCode = 35632;
Jonh.salary = 3500;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O que você está fazendo não é exatamente herança, pois nada no seu objeto `John` é realmente herdado. A herança em JavaScript se dá por meio de uma referência interna chamada *prototype*, que todos os objetos possuem. Ela aponta para um outro objeto, e todas as propriedades e métodos do protótipo são herdadas pelo objeto que contém a referência. No caso do JavaScript, isso é particularmente útil para métodos.

Uma das maneiras de se atribuir *prototype* a um objeto é definir a propriedade `prototype` de uma função, e em seguida invocá-la como construtor utilizando o operador `new`. O objeto instanciado terá como *prototype* o objeto definido como `.prototype` do construtor. Por exemplo:

```
// Define "classe" Pessoa
function Pessoa(nome, idade) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.idade = idade;
}

// Toda pessoa tem uma método fazAniversário
Pessoa.prototype.fazAniversario = function() {
    this.idade++;
}

// Define classe Funcionario
function Funcionario(nome, idade) {
    Pessoa.call(this, nome, idade);
    this.salario = null;
}

// Todo funcionário herda de Pessoa
Funcionario.prototype = Object.create(Pessoa.prototype);

// Teste
var joao = new Funcionario('João', 25);
joao.fazAniversario();
alert(joao.idade); // 26
```

A linha do [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) é que faz a herança. `Object.create` recebe um objeto e retorna outro cujo protótipo é o objeto passado. No código acima, esse objeto retornado é usado como protótipo de todas as instâncias de `Funcionario`, que por isso herdam o método `fazAniversario`. Vale apontar que o `Object.create` não é suportado em navegadores antigos como o IE8. O link acima contém um *polyfill* que pode ser utilizado para que esses browsers passem a oferecer suporte parcial a esse método.

Comment: bfavaretto sua explicação sobre o assunto foi muito construtiva, notei que no meu exemplo acima quando eu utilizava o comando instanceof na minha referencia e nas classes Employee e People na classe Employee ele retornava verdadeiro porem na classe People ele retornava falso, já no seu exemplo em ambas as classes o instanceof retorna verdadeiro e isso é bom porque começo a ver fragmentos de polimorfismo. muito obrigado.

Comment: É porque agora você de fato está criando uma cadeia de protótipos, que é exatamente o que o `instanceof` verifica. Que bom que minha resposta ajudou :)

Comment: ok, mas digamos que o funcionário possua um método chamado get/set Salário, se você está sobreescrevendo o objeto anterior este método não irá existir mais, pois a class-mãe não tem o mesmo. Certo ?

Comment: @Douglas não entendi. Onde eu sobrescrevo o objeto anterior? Meu exemplo usa herança.