# Com fazer um iterator/generator no javascript?

Tags: javascript, generators, iterator

No PHP, temos os `Iterators` e o `Generator`.

Exemplo Iterator:

```
$f = new FileSystemIterator(__DIR__);

foreach($f as $file) {
    echo $file->getFilename();
}
```

Exemplo Generator:

```
function sequence($start, $end) {
    for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; ++$i) {
       yield $i;
    }
}

foreach(sequence(1, 10) as $value) {
     echo $value;
}

// Imprime: 12345678910
```

Acho muito interessante a utilização dos dois, principalmente quando se trata do `Iterator` iterando sobre uma lista de objetos.

Existe alguma maneira de criar um  `Iterator` ou `Generator` no Javascript?
E se não, existe alguma maneira de simulá-los?

Comment: Ficou pensando no `Iterators` que escreveu **iteressante**. KKKKKK

Comment: @DeeSouza, é verdade! kkkkkk. Corrigido :|

Comment: Vale ES6? Lá eles são suportados nativamente.

Comment: sim, vale. Lembra daquela pergunta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90290/existe-alguma-forma-de-estender-um-objeto-em-javascript

Comment: Vale, porque aí nós ficamos sabendo das novidades :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A especificação [ECMAScript 6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html) acrescentou *iterators* e *generators* ao núcleo duro da linguagem, porém hoje (final de 2015) ainda há [limitações de suporte nos browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-generators). Vou explicar como funciona/vai funcionar, para que já fiquemos preparados para o futuro :)

### Iterators

Um *iterator* em ES6 é simplesmente um objeto que implementa um método `next`, responsável por retornar o próximo item da sequência – um objeto com as propriedades `done` e `value`. Não há sintaxe nova, o que foi criado é simplesmente um protocolo. Exemplo [da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators):

```
function makeIterator(array){
    var nextIndex = 0;

    return {
       next: function(){
           return nextIndex < array.length ?
               {value: array[nextIndex++], done: false} :
               {done: true};
       }
    }
}

var it = makeIterator(['yo', 'ya']);
console.log(it.next().value); // 'yo'
console.log(it.next().value); // 'ya'
console.log(it.next().done);  // true
```

<sup>http://www.es6fiddle.net/ifjmbbko/</sup>

Em PHP, um *iterator* pode ser enumerado por um `foreach`, porque ele também é `Enumerable`. Em ES6 existe o [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), porém ele não enumera *iterators*, e sim *iterables*, que são objetos que implementam [@@iterator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-iterable-interface) – ou seja, possuem um método com a chave `Symbol.iterator`. Esse método retorna um *iterator*:

```
function makeIterable(array){

    var nextIndex = 0;
    var it = {};
    it[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
        return {
            next: function(){
                return nextIndex < array.length ?
                       {value: array[nextIndex++], done: false} :
                       {done: true};
            } 
        };
    };
    return it;
}

for(let val of makeIterable(['yo', 'ya'])) console.log(val);
```

<sup>http://www.es6fiddle.net/ifjolmy6/</sup>

A maneira mais prática de criar um *iterable* é usar uma função geradora (que já vamos discutir mais adiante):

```
var myIterable = {}
myIterable[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
};

for(let val of myIterable) {
    console.log(val) 
}
```

<sup>http://www.es6fiddle.net/ifjnkxb4/</sup>

Um *iterator* pode ser também *iterable*, o que é mais próximo do que acontece no PHP:

```
function makeIterableIterator(array){

    var nextIndex = 0;
    var it = {};
    it[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
        return this;
    };
    it.next = function(){
        return nextIndex < array.length ?
               {value: array[nextIndex++], done: false} :
               {done: true};
    };

    return it;
}

for(let val of makeIterableIterator(['yo', 'ya'])) console.log(val);
```

<sup>http://www.es6fiddle.net/ifjox839/</sup>

É mais ou menos isso que fazem os *iterables* que são parte do núcleo da linguagem, como `Array`, `Map`, `Set` etc.

Para saber mais sobre *iterables*, recomendo a leitura de [*Iterables and iterators in ECMAScript 6*](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-iteration.html), onde há muitos exemplos.

### Generators

As funções geradoras facilitam a criação de *iterables*. São basicamente funções com a capacidade de suspender sua execução, e mesmo assim manter o estado para a execução seguinte. O ES6 introduziu uma nova sintaxe para isso, [`function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). Exemplo simples da MDN:

```
function* idMaker(){
  var index = 0;
  while(true)
    yield index++;
}

var gen = idMaker();

console.log(gen.next().value); // 0
console.log(gen.next().value); // 1
console.log(gen.next().value); // 2
```

<sup>http://www.es6fiddle.net/ifjpkcxq/</sup>

O gerador criado por `idMaker` é ao mesmo tempo um *iterator* e um *iterable*. A "mágica" fica por conta do [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield), que é quem suspende a execução. Cada vez que o `next` é executado, a função retoma de onde parou, com seu escopo local intacto.

Basicamente, os generators permitem a criação de sequências computadas de maneira "preguiçosa", um valor por vez, conforme os valores são necessários. Eles podem ainda ser combinados com promessas para que seja possível tratar operações assíncronas de maneira semelhante, podem ser encadeados recursivamente, e podem ser trocar dados entre si, permitindo a implementação de co-rotinas.

Comment: Dá pra ir longe neste tema. Decidi parar por aqui para não ficar grande demais nem fugir do que foi perguntado.

Comment: Boa! `+1` isto abre uma porta interessante para [processos assíncronos muito interessantes](http://davidwalsh.name/async-generators).

Comment: Os links dos fiddles já não estão a funcionar