# Como funciona o yield* no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Vi em alguns trechos de código a palavra-chave `yield*`. Ela é diferente do `yield`?

Pesquisando sobre, cheguei a o seguinte exemplo de código:

```
function* g1() {
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
  yield 4;
}
```

O que faz o `*` ao lado da *keyword* `function`? Tem a ver com o `*` ao lado de `yield`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Geradores

A sintaxe `function*` é utilizada para definir um gerador e `yield` é o análogo a `return` para um gerador.

### O que é?

Gerador é considerado como uma função especial, responsável por criar um iterador. É caracterizado por calcular cada item pertencente ao elemento iterável por vez, ao invés de armazená-los todos em memória, como é feito sem o gerador. Característica esta que é conhecida por [*lazy evaluation*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o_pregui%C3%A7osa).

### Exemplo

Consideremos a sequência de Fibonacci, que cada elemento consiste na soma dos dois elementos anteriores. Sem utilizar um gerador, poderíamos fazer:

```js
function fibonacci(n) {
  let sequence = [];
  
  sequence.push(0, 1);
  
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    sequence.push(sequence[i - 1] + sequence[i - 2]);
  }
  
  return sequence;
}

const sequence = fibonacci(10);

console.log(sequence.length);
```

O código acima irá gerar uma saída igual a 10, referente ao número de posições armazenadas em memória para a sequência. Para quantias pequenas, isso não afetaria a aplicação, mas se considerarmos um valor gigantesto, tal como um milhão de elementos, isso provavelmente afetaria o rendimento da sua aplicação.

Com o uso do gerador:

```js
function* fibonacci(n) {
  let a = 0, b = 1, current;
  
  while (true) {
    current = a;
    
    yield current;
    
    a = b;
    b = current + b;
  }
}

const sequence = fibonacci(10);

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(sequence.next().value);
}
```

Os elementos da lista não estarão em memória quando fizermos `const sequence = fibonacci(10)`, os mesmos serão calculados dentro do `for`, apenas quando forem utilizados, através de `sequence.next()`. Mas e se a lista precisar ter um milhão de elementos? Sem problemas, como os elementos não ficam em memória, o gerador não afetará na sua aplicação (tempo de execução continuaria alto, pois continuaria a ser executado milhões de operações, mas na memória, não seria afetado).

### Iterador

O retorno de um gerador é um [iterador](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) e, portanto, implementa o método `next`.

[image: Tabela que descreve o método next.]

### Utilização

Imagine que você deseja exibir uma lista com todos os nomes das cidades do Brasil, que totalizam um número de aproximadamente 5570, utilizando *infinite scroll*. Armazenar em memória os dados destes 5570 registros seria desnecessário, pois dificilmente o usuário usará todos eles. Então você poderia exibir em tela uma quantidade inicial, 20 por exemplo, e quando o usuário requerir mais, ao atingir o final da lista, fazer, com o gerador, uma requisição AJAX para o servidor solicitando mais 10 registros e adicionando-os à lista. Desta forma, os 5570 registros só estariam em memória se o usuário solicitasse isso.

### Relacionados

- [Com fazer um iterator/generator no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91400/com-fazer-um-iterator-generator-no-javascript)
- [Quais as vantagens de usar um "generator" (yield) no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50208/quais-as-vantagens-de-usar-um-generator-yield-no-php)
- [Iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

> A sequência de Fibonacci, embora não muito utilizada na prática, foi usada como exemplo devido a facilidade de implementação.

Comment: Interessante! Então para operações desse tipo convém usar a mecânica do `yield` mesmo? Visto que ela possui impacto muito menor no uso de memória..

Comment: Caramba que resposta. +1

Comment: Muito obrigado! Se eu pudesse dar +2 eu dava, por causa da ideia de usar em _infinite scroll_, que é uma prática muito comum nos meus projetos!

Comment: @ArturTrapp, adicionei o comentário à resposta.

Comment: Existe alguma maneira de transformar um gerador em array diretamente?

Comment: @Miguel, acredito que com o `Array.from`, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, sem problema quando chegar a casa vejo isso. Boa resposta