# Programa que retorna os números não comuns de duas listas (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou tentando fazer um programa, em Python, que retorna uma lista com os elementos não comuns entre duas outras listas. Fiz o seguinte código:

```
def indice(a,b):
    ind = []
    for i in range (len(a)):
        for w in range (len(b)):
            if not (a[i] in b) and not (b[w] in a):
                ind = ind + [a[i]] + [b[w]]
    return ind
```

Porém, ele apresenta, eventualmente, repetições na lista retornada e, quando a primeira lista comparada tem mais elementos que a segunda, a função retorna uma lista vazia. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Por questões de legibilidade do código, recomenda-se utilizar `x not in y` ao invés de `not x in y`, mesmo que ambas as expressões sejam avaliadas da mesma maneira: `not y.__contains__(x)`.

Comment: em uma nota separada: algum bom motivo pra você estar estudando Python 2?  A última versão é de 2010, e ele  não terá mais atualizações - o melhor é prosseguir com Python 3.6

Answer (score 7):

Aqui tens uma maneira equivalente à da resposta do @nano.galvao:

```
nao_comuns = list(set(a) ^ set(b))
```

Mas de uma forma didática e programando a funcionalidade podes fazer sem usar dois ciclos (comentei no código algumas explicações):

```
def nao_comuns(a,b):
    a_b = a+b # juntar as duas para percorrer todos os elementos
    nao_comuns = []
    for ele in a_b:
        if ele not in a or ele not in b: # nao existe numa delas
            nao_comuns.append(ele)
    return nao_comuns

a = range(10) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = range(0,20,2) # [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
print nao_comuns(a,b) # [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/IqmVE3)

Com list compreension podes fazer esse ciclo numa linha:

```
def nao_comuns(a,b):
    a_b = a+b # juntar as duas para percorrer todos os elementos
    return [ele for ele in a_b if ele not in a or ele not in b]

a = range(10) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = range(0,20,2) # [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
print nao_comuns(a,b) # [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/6O6Xrn)

Usando um *[generator](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191752/como-funciona-o-yield-no-javascript/191780#191780)*:

```
def nao_comuns(a,b):
    a_b = a+b # juntar as duas para percorrer todos os elementos
    for ele in a_b:
        if ele not in a or ele not in b: # nao existe numa delas
            yield ele

a = range(10) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = range(0,20,2) # [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
print list(nao_comuns(a,b)) # [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/t8TJ5C)

Answer (score 4):

```
def elementos_nao_comuns(a,b):
    return list(set(a).symmetric_difference(set(b)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Já agora uma solução um bocado primitiva usando conjuntos:

1) não comuns(a,b)= a∪b  -  a∩b

```
list((set(a) | set(b)) - (set(a) & set(b)))
```

2) não comuns(a,b)= a-b   ∪    b-a

```
list(set(a)-set(b) | set(b)-set(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

Boa noite, seguindo sua lógica acredito que o mais correto seria:

```
def indice(a,b):
    ind = [];
    for ea in a:
        if (not (ea in b)):
            ind.append(ea);
    for eb in b:
        if (not (eb in a)):
            ind.append(eb);
    return ind;
```

Você percorre item a item de cada lista sempre olhando se o elemento não existe na outra ponta.