# Extrai dados de Array em Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Possuo um `array` com os grupos de trabalho que o usuário da sessão pertence, por exemplo se eu escrevo assim:

```
return $data.teste02[0].group_id.name
```

Ele me retorna o primeiro grupo que esse usuário pertence, que nesse caso seria **administrador** 
Porém há casos que o usuário da sessão irá pertencer a mais de um grupo, e preciso saber todos os grupos de trabalho que ele pertence, então pensei em fazer um `for` para conseguir acessar todos os grupos, pensando nisso fiz o seguinte código:

```
for (var x = 0; x <= $data.teste02.length; x++){
   return $data.teste02[x].group_id.name;
}
```

Porém mesmo assim ele só me retorna o grupo de trabalho da primeira posição.
Se tiverem alguma ideia de como posso alcançar isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao dar um return dentro de um for, ele implicitamente aplica um `break` então sua estrutura de repetição descrita acima irá parar na primeira interação.

É muito comum usar isso se você está buscando um valor específico, ou irá dar um retorno binário.

Então, como  é possível haver múltiplos grupos, a solução é acumular em um outro array  e retornar apenas os nomes do grupo.

```
var grupos = [];
for (var x in $data.teste02){
   grupos.push($data.teste02[x].group_id.name);
}
return grupos ;
```

Com isso você poderia validar se o usuário está em um grupo usando o método [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) por exemplo.

```
if(grupos.indexOf('administrador') != -1){
  //Grupo administrador
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, a ideia de adicionar em outro array funcionou perfeitamente. Assim que ficar disponível já marco sua resposta como correta.

Answer (score 3):

Se queres criar uma nova array com os nomes podes usar o `.map()` assim:

```
var grupos = $data.teste02.map(el => el.group_id.name);
```

Assim ficas com uma nova array, com o mesmo tamanho mas só com `group_id.name`.

Comment: Por algum motivo o `for` ainda é mais performático que o map: https://jsperf.com/map-vs-for-loop-performance/6

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho para mim dá-me que `.map()` é mais rápido (https://snag.gy/H2kqoR.jpg). Mas neste caso a questão de semântica faz-me também preferir o `.map()`, porque estamos exatamente a mapear dados.

Comment: De acordo, se o objetivo for apenas mapear um determinado dado sim. Porém já vi programadores usarem map para operações lógicas e condicionais por preguiça de montar um for rs

Comment: E semântica é tudo em um código...

Answer (score 3):

> *This is a new technology, part of the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard.*

A título de curiosidade, utilizando geradores também é possível fazer basicamente seguindo sua lógica. Veja um exemplo:

```
function* get_group_names(data)
{
    for (let group of data.teste2) {
        yield group.group_id.name;
    }
}
```

Ou, alternativamente, como comentado pelo Sérgio, utilizar `{group_id}` no `for`, sendo este o equivalente à `group.group_by` do código anterior:

```
function* get_group_names(data)
{
    for (let {group_id} of data.teste2) {
        yield group_id.name;
    }
}
```

Desta forma, para obter a lista de nomes dos grupos, basta converter o gerador para *array*:

```
const groups = Array.from(get_group_names($data));
```

Ou mesmo percorrê-lo através de um laço de repetição:

```
for (let group of get_group_names($data)) {
    console.log(group);
}
```

Referências:

[function* - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

[for...of - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

[Como funciona o yield* no Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191752/5878)

Veja funcionando abaixo.

```js
const $data = {
  'teste2': [{
    'group_id': {
      'name': 'Grupo 1'
    },

  }, {
    'group_id': {
      'name': 'Grupo 2'
    },

  }, {
    'group_id': {
      'name': 'Grupo 3'
    },

  }]
};

function* get_group_names(data) {
  for (let group of data.teste2) {
    yield group.group_id.name;
  }
}

// Converte o gerador para array:
console.log(Array.from(get_group_names($data)));

// Ou percorre o gerador com um laço de repetição:
for (let group of get_group_names($data)) {
  console.log(group);
}
```

Comment: `+1` pelos gerador. E podia até ser `for (let {group_id} of data.teste2) yield group_id.name;` Mas ainda prefiro `.map()` neste caso.

Comment: Muito interessante o gerador(+1), o problema é a compatibilidade com navegadores legados. O safari já suporta `yield`  ?

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho Aparentemente, sim: https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-generators