# Como acessar um array de forma circular?

Tags: javascript, array

Considerando que eu tenha um `array`:

```
const a = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
```

Gostaria de criar uma função que retorne um item e, a cada chamada, retorne o subsequente, e ao chegar ao final, que retorne o primeiro novamente. Ou seja:

- Chamada 1 retorna `A`;
- Chamada 2 retorna `B`;
- Chamada 3 retorna `C`;
- Chamada 4 retorna `A`;
- Chamada 5 retorna `B`;

E assim sucessivamente.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> **AVISO**
>
> Relendo esta resposta dois anos depois, **NÃO** me parece um bom caso de uso para um iterator... Não tem nenhuma necessidade, é só firula sintática e provavelmente tem impacto na performance. Devo ter escrito isso como forma de estudar iterators na época, e para colocar mais um método de se fazer isso entre as respostas. Se eu fosse responder hoje, provavelmente sugeriria [algo como o que sugeriu o Augusto Vasques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/385148) ou o [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/372147).
>
> Então reforço o aviso: **você provavelmente não precisa de um iterator para isso!!!**

Parece um bom caso de uso para um [*iterator*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91400/com-fazer-um-iterator-generator-no-javascript) (criado aqui com uma *generator function*):

```js
function* indiceArray(tamanho) {
    let indice = 0;
    while(true) {
        yield indice;
        indice = (indice + 1) % tamanho;
    }
    return indice;
}

const a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
const indice = indiceArray(a.length);

console.log(a[indice.next().value])
console.log(a[indice.next().value])
console.log(a[indice.next().value])
console.log(a[indice.next().value])
```

Comment: Eu fiz um benchmark por curiosidade e, realmente, a diferença de performance é drástica... [Ver aqui.](https://jsbench.me/l7ksispu3q/1) De todo modo, ainda acho que seja uma solução super interessante. Uma pena que a performance de iteradores ainda é ruim (e tendo em vista o que fazem deveria ser exímia). Espero que isso um dia melhore.

Answer (score 13):

Uma alternativa é usar [*closures*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/112052):

```js
function makeCircular(arr) {
  var current = 0;
  return function() {
    return arr[current++ % arr.length];
  }
}

const a = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
let next = makeCircular(a);

// imprime A, B, C, A, B, C...
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    console.log(next());
}
```

`makeCircular(a)` recebe um array e retorna outra função, que por sua vez, retorna, a cada chamada, o próximo valor do array de maneira circular.

Você pode inclusive criar vários *closures* diferentes para o mesmo array, e cada um mantém seu estado individualmente:

```js
function makeCircular(arr) {
  var current = 0;
  return function() {
    return arr[current++ % arr.length];
  }
}

const a = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
let next = makeCircular(a);
let next2 = makeCircular(a);

console.log(next()); // A
console.log(next()); // B
console.log(next2()); // A
console.log(next()); // C
```

---

Só um detalhe: o contador interno (`current`) pode dar problema se ele atingir o valor de [`Number.MAX_VALUE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE):

```js
function makeCircular(arr) {
  var current = Number.MAX_VALUE; // começando em MAX_VALUE só pra mostrar o problema
  return function() {
    return arr[current++ % arr.length];
  }
}

const a = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
let next = makeCircular(a);

// imprime C 20 vezes
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    console.log(next());
}
```

No caso, imprimiu "C" 20 vezes, indicando que quando atingir `MAX_VALUE`, ele não consegue mais incrementar o valor (testei no Chrome e Firefox e o comportamento foi o mesmo).

Tudo bem que, segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE#Description), o valor de `MAX_VALUE` é aproximadamente 2<sup>1024</sup>, o que deve ser mais que suficiente para grande parte das aplicações.

Mas se quiser evitar esta - rara - situação, pode manter o valor de `current` sempre menor que o tamanho do array:

```js
function makeCircular(arr) {
  var current = -1;
  return function() {
    current = (current + 1) % arr.length;
    return arr[current];
  }
}

const a = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
let next = makeCircular(a);

// imprime A, B, C, A, B, C...
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    console.log(next());
}
```

---

#### Generalizando a solução

Por fim, dá para generalizar esta solução para avançar uma quantidade arbitrária de elementos, em vez de pegar sempre o próximo. Além disso, daria para setar também a posição inicial:

```js
// para módulo funcionar com números negativos
function mod(n, m) {
    return ((n % m) + m) % m;
}

// default é começar do primeiro elemento, e avançar de 1 em 1 (funciona igual à solução anterior)
function makeCircular(arr, start = 0, step = 1) {
    var first = true;
    var current;
    return function () {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
            current = mod(start, arr.length);
        } else {
            current = mod(current + step, arr.length);
        }
        return arr[current];
    }
}
    
const a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
let next = makeCircular(a, 0, 8); // começa do primeiro, avança de 8 em 8
// imprime A, D, B, E, C, A, D...
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(next());
}

// ou, com passos negativos
console.log('com passo negativo');
next = makeCircular(a, 2, -8); // começa do terceiro, retrocede de 8 em 8
// imprime C, E, B, D, A, C...
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(next());
}

console.log('com índice inicial negativo');
next = makeCircular(a, -1, 2); // começa do último, avança de 2 em 2
// imprime E, B, D, A, C, E...
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(next());
}
```

Só tive que fazer um ajuste para o módulo quando há números negativos envolvidos, já que em JavaScript `-1 % 5` é igual a `-1`, mas no nosso caso precisaria que fosse `4` (ler [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/516147/112052) pode ajudar a entender).

Desta forma, é possível usar tanto o passo quanto o índice inicial negativo (por exemplo, `start` igual a `-1` começa do último elemento, `-2` de penúltimo, etc; e para um array com 5 elementos, `start` igual a `-6` também começaria do último).

Answer (score 11):

A seguinte função retorna o item subsequente a cada chamada

```js
var arr = ["A", "B", "C"];

function getItem(arr) {
    arr.push(arr.shift());
    return arr[arr.length - 1];
}

console.log(getItem(arr));
console.log(getItem(arr));
console.log(getItem(arr));
console.log(getItem(arr));
console.log(getItem(arr));
```

O funcionamento é baseado em [pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15698/77268). O primeiro elemento do array é sempre removido e colocado na ultima posição, ou seja, no topo. A cada chamada da função, a estrutura do array é atualizada por meio do `arr.push()` responsável por empilhar o primeiro elemento removido pela função `arr.shift()`.

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483149/how-to-access-array-in-circular-manner-in-javascript)

Comment: E aquele `alert`, o `slice` e o `join` são pra que?

Comment: @Sorack removidos :)

Answer (score 6):

Uma alternativa seria também dispor a opção de definir um limite para a sua função, isto é, repetir os valores do *array* até uma determinada quantidade. Para isso, você poderia definir um gerador e controlar a quantidade de itens já retornados anteriormente:

```
function* repeat(array, n = Infinity) {
    loop: while (true) {
        for (const item of array) {
            if (!n--) {
                break loop;
            }

            yield item;
        }
    }
}
```

Assim, fazendo `repeat([1, 2, 3])` irá repetir os três valores infinitamente, mas se você atribuir um limite em `n`, `repeat([1, 2, 3], 5)`, irá repetir até gerar cinco valores, `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]`.

```js
function* repeat(array, n = Infinity) {
  loop: while (true) {
    for (const item of array) {
      if (!n--) {
        break loop;
      }

      yield item;
    }
  }
}

const items = repeat([1, 2, 3], 5);

for (const item of items) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Se não quiser perder tempo:**

Para fazer um array usar índices circulares ao final basta usar a fórmula:

**`indíce normalizado = resto(indice estrapolado, comprimento da array)`**

Lembrando que resto em JavaScript é `%`.

```js
const arr = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

const len = arr.length;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log("arr[" + i + "]= " + arr[i % len]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Bom vou entrar no jogo também e sugerir adicionar uma propriedade não interável ao seu array:

```js
function adicionaNext(obj) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, 'next', {
    value: (i => function() { return this[i++ % this.length] })(0)
  })
}

const arr = ['A', 'B', 'C']
adicionaNext(arr)

console.log(arr.next())
console.log(arr.next())
console.log(arr.next())
console.log(arr.next())
console.log(arr.next())
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando closures, é possível gerar uma função `foo` que, sempre que invocada, retorna o próximo elemento do array, ainda que ele seja modificado no decorrer do código.

```js
function getElement(list) {
    if (!Array.isArray(list)) {
        throw new Error('list deve ser array.');
    }

    let index = list.length - 1;

    function next() {
        index = (index + 1)%list.length;
        return list[index];
    }

    return next;
}

const a = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
const foo = getElement(a);

// testando
console.log('a = ', a);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(foo());
}
console.log('inserindo D');
a.push('D');
console.log('a = ', a);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(foo());
}
console.log('deletando B, C');
a.splice(1, 2);
console.log('a = ', a);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log('->', foo());
}
```