# Função para fazer fila andar no Array, primeiro vira o ultimo em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

preciso fazer uma função que no Array está cadastrado:

```
Wesley
Welson
Gabriel
```

apos ser chamada, retorne:

```
Welson
Gabriel
Wesley
```

isso em JavaScript

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como acessar um array de forma circular?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/372093/como-acessar-um-array-de-forma-circular)

Comment: Não definitivamente, o que preciso é retornar tudo do array, só que mudando as posições como demonstrado no exemplo da pergunta, mas talvez com está solução, eu chegue lá, criando subArrays dentro do array, daí só mudava a posição do Array 

Comment: Você quer rotacionar o array?

Comment: @AugustoVasques, isso, não havia encontrado a palavra certa kkk, é isso mesmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [sintaxe de de propagação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) para fazer a rotação a esquerda dos elementos da array.

```js
let nomes = ["Wesley", "Welson", "Gabriel"]

let rotação = [...nomes.slice(1, nomes.length), nomes[0]]

console.log(rotação)
```

Só empacotar como função para se adequar ao problema:

```js
let nomes = ["Wesley", "Welson", "Gabriel"]

function rotacionarEsquesda(array) {
  return [...array.slice(1, array.length), array[0]]
}

console.log(rotacionarEsquesda(nomes))
```

Comment: Deu certo, consegui fazer, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Nos baseando nas respostas da pergunta ["Como acessar um array de forma circular?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/372093/como-acessar-um-array-de-forma-circular) podemos chegar a uma função que utiliza a função `shift` do `array` para retornar sempre uma cópia com as ordens diferentes:

```js
const circular = (base) => {
  let arr = [...base];

  return () => {
    const primeiro = arr.shift();
    arr = [...arr, primeiro];
    return arr;
  }
};

const listar = circular(['Wesley', 'Welson', 'Gabriel']);

console.log(listar());
console.log(listar());
```

Comment: muito obrigado, resolveu também, mas utilizei a função do Augusto Vasques