# Como funciona a função "next" no Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Segue o exemplo:

```
@Output() exemplo = new Subject<{ valor1: number, valor2: number }>();

this.exemplo.next({ valor1: _valor1, valor2: this.valor });
```

- O que está acontecendo aqui?
- É passado um objeto como parâmetro?

Comment: Na verdade acredito que isto tenha mais a ver com [Generators](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91400/com-fazer-um-iterator-generator-no-javascript) do que com Angular propriamente dito

Comment: Apenas com este código não tem como afirmar nada, o método **next()** no **`Angular`** pode ser aplicado em diversos contextos, ele pode ser executado a partir de um Observable, ou em um Subject por exemplo, isso já explica alguma coisa, pois ambos ficam "observando" alterações em algum valor declarado.

Comment: Acrescentei uma linha de código ao exemplo. Parece que tem o Subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao instanciar um `Subject` é necessário informar qual o tipo de dado que irá trabalhar, por exemplo: `new Subject<number>();`. No seu exemplo o tipo de objeto que o `Subject` irá trabalhar é um objeto com a seguinte estrutura: `{ valor1: number, valor2: number }`, ou seja, o objeto deverá ter dois campos do tipo `number` com os nomes "valor1" e "valor2".

Ao utilizar a função `next` você emite um valor para os subscribers, em outros termos mais simples, você publica um valor para quem estiver ouvindo.

Veja este pequeno exemplo retirado da [documentação](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject):

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

const subject = new Subject<number>();

subject.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log(`observerA: ${v}`)
});
subject.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log(`observerB: ${v}`)
});

subject.next(1);
subject.next(2);

// Logs:
// observerA: 1
// observerB: 1
// observerA: 2
// observerB: 2
```

Se quiser se aprofundar no assunto:

- https://medium.com/@marcelo.vismari/angular-rxjs-cold-e-hot-observable-557f04cb2e3d
- https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject