# Iteradores JavaScript

Tags: javascript

O que são Iteradores JavaScript ?
Para que servem o `next()` e o `[symbol.iterator]`?

Não estou entendendo bem sobre esse assunto de **Iteradores** preciso que alguém me diga como fazer pra entender, já procurei por aí mas é mais difícil ainda de entender!

Comment: Relacionado: [Com fazer um iterator/generator no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91400/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [Como funciona o yield* no JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191752/3774)