# Usando Prototype no JS

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Estou precisando de uma ajuda na utilização do Prototypes, estou querendo organizar e manter um código mais limpo e podendo reutilizar as minhas classes em outros momentos... E nas pesquisas a utilização do Prototype parecer ser algo vantajoso... (posso ter entedido errado, me corrijam...)

Primeiramente vou colocar meu código abaixo e a seguir minhas dúvidas...

```
var Model = function(hello) {
    this.hello = hello; 

    //meu teste
    this._init();
}

Model.prototype = function(){
    var _init = function(){
        console.log("Init...");

        this.helloWorld();
    },

    _helloWorld = function(){
        alert(this.hello)
    };

    return {
        helloWorld : _helloWorld
    };
}();
```

1° Dúvida:  Dentro do meu Construtor como poderia chamar a minha função "_init"? Como ela é privada, gostaria que ficasse a primeira chamada dentro do construtor.. 
No meu exemplo acima, eu fiz a chamada via "this._init()", mas tive o erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._init is not a function
```

2° Dúvida: Dentro da minha função "_init" poderei, e terei chamadas de outros métodos, neste exemplo: "_helloWorld", a forma que fiz funcionaria? Ou qual a forma correta?

Valeu Pessoal.

Comment: Curiosidade: por que não usa a classe do JS neste caso?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tem um exemplo? Como comentei, a principio a forma de estruturar código assim me agradou... Mas, estou aberto a novas dicas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A questão é que você não exportou a função `_init` para o corpo do *prototype*, assim como fez com a função `helloWorld`; desta forma, ela só existirá no escopo local da função que define o *prototype*, mas não no objeto em si. Para resolver, basta exportar a função:

```js
var Model = function(hello) {
    this.hello = hello; 

    // Chamando o método "init"
    this.init();
}

Model.prototype = function(){
    var _init = function(){
        console.log("Init...");

        this.helloWorld();
    },

    _helloWorld = function(){
        console.log('Hello ' + this.hello)  // Alterei para console.log para facilitar a visualização
    };

    return {
        init: _init,  // Exportanto para o prototype a função _init
        helloWorld : _helloWorld
    };
}();

const m = new Model('world');
```

Mas no ES6 foi definida a estrutura de classe no JavaScript e tem um [suporte muito bom](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class) já, exceto na família IE. Com ela, você pode fazer:

```js
class Model {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
  
  hello() {
    console.log('Hello ' + this.name)
  }
}

const m = new Model('world')

m.hello()
```

Você pode ler mais sobre as classes em [MDN: Classes no JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

**Relacionadas:**

- [Existe classe em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108548/5878)
- [Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/5878)
- [Qual é o paradigma de programação usado pelo JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126886/5878)
- [O que é Protótipo Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42962/5878)
- [Existe alguma forma de estender um objeto em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90290/5878)

Comment: uma pergunta, dentro da função "Init", eu conseguiria chamar o método "_helloWorld" ao invés de exportar o HelloWorld no prototype? A ideia era que o _helloWorld, por exemplo, seria um método privado e não poderia ser acessado diretamente m.helloWorld(), agradeço a sua ajuda!!!

Comment: @RoniSommerfeld Consegue, mas com um detalhe. Neste caso, a função `_helloWorld` não estará associada ao objeto, sendo uma função normal, não um método, o que implica que o `this` dentro de `_helloWorld` não apontará para o seu objeto, mas sim para a própria função. Desta forma, você precisará passar o objeto que deseja trabalhar via parâmetro. Veja um exemplo: https://repl.it/@acwoss/PreciousTartActivecontent

Comment: agora consegui entender...Era isso que gostaria de saber. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!