# Como fazer herança com JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Estou com um dúvida de como usar herança com JavaScript / jQuery (se é possível), dei uma pesquisada mas encontrei materiais confusos de gringos o quais não conseguiram me auxiliar.

Vamos para o exemplo clássico de Pessoa / PessoaFisica.

```js
// Arquivo PessoaModal.js
var Pessoa = function(id , nome , status){
  this.id = id;
  this.nome = nome;
  this.status = status;
};

Pessoa.prototype = {
  getId : function(){
    return this.id;
  } ,
  setId : function(id){
    this.id = id;
  } ,
  getNome : function(){
      return this.id;
  } ,
  setNome : function(nome){
    this.nome = nome;
  } ,
  getStatus : function(){
      return this.id;
  } ,
  setStatus : function(status){
    this.status = status;
  } ,
  __get : function(propriedade){
    return this[propriedade];
  } ,
  __set : functoin(propriedade , valor){
    this[propriedade] = valor;
}

// PessoaFisicaModal
var PessoaFisica = function(rg , cpf){
  this.rg = rg;
  this.cpf = cpf;
};

PessoaFisica.prototype = {
  getRg : function(){
    return this.rg;
  } ,
  setRg : function(rg){
    this.rg = rg;
  } ,
  getCpf : function(){
    return.cpf;
  } ,
  setCpf : function(cpf){
    this.cpf = cpf;
  } ,
  __get : function(propriedade){
    return this[propriedade];
  } ,
  __set : function(propriedade , valor){
    this[propriedade] = valor;
  }
};
```

no exemplo acima, com faria para que a PessoaFisica herdasse as propriedades e os métodos da PessoaModal (SuperClass) ?

Comment: Sugiro que você de uma olhada nesse link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7220/este-%C3%A9-um-exemplo-correto-de-heran%C3%A7a-em-javascript.
Lá tem como poderá ser respondida sua dúvida, ou pelo menos dar uma luz para o que você precisa

Comment: Em jQuery não dá: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/101

Comment: Muito bom a explicação sugerida, agora consigo usar todos os meus metodos da SUPERCLASSS para as filhas. Parabens @Ricardo Lucas.