# JavaScript é uma linguagem Orientada a Objetos?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, característica-linguagem, protótipo

Muitos dizem que ela não é uma linguagem orientada a objetos, por não ser possível definir classes nela, até sua versão ECMAScript 5, porém com a utilização de funções construtoras e prototipação é possível implementar muitos dos conceitos de Orientação a Objetos, como Herança, Encapsulamento, Sobrecarga etc.

Então certamente ela pode ser considerada como uma linguagem orientada a objetos, apesar de ser baseada em protótipos?

Comment: Ela pode ser usada orientada a objetos e não orientada a objetos.

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Só por não ter classes? Eu não gosto da orientação a objetos via protótipos (caso do JavaScript), mas é possível argumentar que ela é _mais pura_ do que a orientação a objetos baseada em classes. Objeto herda de objeto, por exemplo.

Comment: @Pablo Almeida  ok, então ela só é orientada a objetos.

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108548/existe-classe-em-javascript

Answer (score 26):

Yure, isto vai depender um pouco da sua intepretação do que é Orientação à objetos.

por exemplo, se você fizer uma pesquisa no [`Dev Mozilla`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript), você verá que segundo a interpretação deles, JavaScript é Orientado a objetos, porém usa um modelo que não utiliza de classes.

Porém há que diga que programação baseada em protótipos não é simplesmente um modelo de OOP, mas um paradigma completo, no caso orientação à protótipos.

sei que a pergunta se resume ao `ECMA5`, mas o `ECMA6` trás o conceito de classe e herança para o `JavaScript`, como no exemplo abaixo retirado de [`ECMAScript 6 — New Features`](http://es6-features.org/#ClassInheritance)

```
class Rectangle extends Shape {
    constructor (id, x, y, width, height) {
        super(id, x, y)
        this.width  = width
        this.height = height
    }
}
class Circle extends Shape {
    constructor (id, x, y, radius) {
        super(id, x, y)
        this.radius = radius
    }
}
```

mesmo que não possa utilizar o `ECMA6` (atualmente este é somente viavel no lado do servidor, como em um serviço feito em NodeJS, uma vez que a maioria dos browsers ainda não dão suporte ao `ECMA6`), você ainda pode usar o [`TypeScript`](https://www.typescriptlang.org) e escrever códigos como o mostrado abaixo (exemplo retirado da documentação do `TypeScript`).

```
class Animal {
    name: string;
    constructor(theName: string) { this.name = theName; }
    move(distanceInMeters: number = 0) {
        console.log(`${this.name} moved ${distanceInMeters}m.`);
    }
}

class Snake extends Animal {
    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }
    move(distanceInMeters = 5) {
        console.log("Slithering...");
        super.move(distanceInMeters);
    }
}

class Horse extends Animal {
    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }
    move(distanceInMeters = 45) {
        console.log("Galloping...");
        super.move(distanceInMeters);
    }
}
```

lembrado que o `TypeScript` é um `JavaScript pre-compilado`, algo semelhante ao que acontece com o `LESS` e o `SASS`, então será necessário uma ferramenta que converta o `TypeScript` em `JavaScript`, eu particulamente aconselho o uso do [`Gulp`](http://gulpjs.com), [`Grunt`](http://gruntjs.com) ou [`BundleTransformer`](https://github.com/Taritsyn/BundleTransformer), após a escolha de uma ferramenta, você terá que baixar o seu respectivo modulo:

- [`gulp-typescript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript)
- [`grunt-typescript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-typescript)
- [`Bundle Transformer: TypeScript`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.TypeScript/)

Comment: +1 pelo TypeScript. <3

Comment: Na versão atual do Javascript ja é possivel utilizar classes ?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class

Comment: @Rogi93 se estiver utilizando Webpack ou um polyfill, sem problemas, se precisar dá suporte apenas as os navegadores atuais (consulte o site i can use), sem problemas.

Comment: @TobiasMesquita entendi, obg.

Comment: Ah mano, como eu amo Typescript...

Answer (score 21):

## TL;DR

Eu respondo isso em boa medida na pergunta [Qual é o paradigma de programação usado pelo JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126886/101). Então já começo dizendo que [JavaScript é multi-paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129597/101), entre eles a orientação a objeto.

## Introdução

Falo sobre [O que é paradigma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101). Por essa definição JS é essencialmente imperativa e possui alguns recursos que facilitam a orientação a objeto. É importante entender [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101).

Falo sobre o [Significado da terminologia "Orientado a objeto"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101). Ali não há uma resposta definitiva, há muita controvérsia sobre o que OOP realmente é. Vou falar aqui no que é mais aceito em programação (não em *design*) e que pode ajudar definir se a linguagem é ou não orientada a objeto. Lá define o que é um objeto que é importante para começarmos entender se há orientação.

Há outras definições que não gosto tanto: [O que é "Orientado a objeto" e quais outros métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108047/101). Também há questionamento se [Existe classe em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108548/101) e é um leitura importante. Leitura complementar: [Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos. O que são e quais suas principais diferenças?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/101).

Lembrando que você [pode fazer orientação a objeto até em Assembly](http://www.drdobbs.com/embedded-systems/object-oriented-programming-in-assembly/184408319). Ou em C: [É possível programar orientado a objeto em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80228/101).

## Não é tão claro se é ou não

Por todas definições que encontrei JS é OO (como paradigma secundário). Em menor grau que outras linguagens. Ela é mais especificamente orientada a protótipos, que não deixam de ser objetos. A [orientação a protótipos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) é um ramo da orientação a objetos. A Linguagem não é [orientada à classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming).

Se ainda não acredita, leia a [documentação que é considerada oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript). Note que eles não falam que a linguagem é orientada a objeto. De uma certa forma nenhuma linguagem é de um paradigma. Você aplica paradigmas no seu código. Mas é claro que as linguagens incentivam um certo paradigma.

JS incentiva a orientação a objeto? Depende da definição de OOP que você use e depende da definição do que é incentivar.

Você chama membros de uma estrutura, incluindo funções/métodos, se referenciando pelo objeto primariamente. Alguns dizem que isso já é suficiente para ser orientado a objeto. Outros dirão que precisa poder fazer herança, polimorfismo e encapsulamento.

- Um objeto pode ser criado baseado em outro existente - que será um protótipo deste (veja exemplo em outras respostas);
- um objeto pode assumir comportamentos diferentes de forma consistente com sua "família";
- um objeto pode esconder os detalhes de como ele funciona.

Pode-se argumentar que a sintaxe não é a mais conveniente para fazer isso. Mas bem fácil entender o funcionamento. Há mecanismo específicos que "incentivam" fazer essas coisas. Se eles são suficientes eu não sei, acho que aí caímos na subjetividade. Objetivamente os mecanismos existem.

Alguns falam que é necessário abstração e/ou sobrecarga de operadores. Mas são poucas fontes que citam essas características como obrigatórias e não são as mais confiáveis. É possível fazer abstração em JS, mas não há mecanismo específico. De qualquer forma é uma coisa mais de *design*. Sobrecarga de operador realmente não tem nada, mas é um recurso controverso se faz parte de OO. Java não faz isso e ninguém questiona se a linguagem é orientada a objeto.

Pra falar a verdade conheço muita gente que não acha a sintaxe de classe tão conveniente assim. Claro, estão tão acostumados com os protótipos que dificulta a adaptação.

Por outro lado há quem fale que OOP é sobre o [reúso de código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/434920/101). JS é uma das linguagens mais simples de obter isso. Se disser que OO é colocar estado junto com comportamento, é bem fácil, o fato de ser opcional fazer isso não muda nada.

Não há pureza em JS. Mas qual linguagem é pura? E nem é uma boa característica.

O fato dela ser orientada a protótipos não elimina o fato de ser orientada a objetos também, assim como não elimina o fato de ser principalmente imperativa.

## ES6

[EcmaScript6](http://es6-features.org/) trouxe as classes para a linguagem. Note que não houve alterações semânticas importantes. Basicamente existe uma nova sintaxe para fazer o que já era possível, agora com classes. Sintaxe é importante, claro. Sempre dizemos que C pode ser programada orientada a objeto, mesmo sem a linguagem ser. JS não tinha facilidades para escrever classes, ainda que os objetos podiam ser criados sem elas.

Agora JS é orientada a protótipos e à classes. Mudou alguma coisa em relação a orientação a objetos? Me parece que não. Se não mudou nada, parece que a linguagem já era orientada a objeto antes de existir classes.

Quem não pode usar ES6, pode usar [TypeScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101) e ter a orientação a objeto em sua forma clássica ([veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49408/101)).

## Conclusão

Eu considero que **a linguagem pode ser chamada de orientada a objeto**, acho que a maioria das pessoas acham assim. Faz pouca diferença prática saber disso, mas é uma informação útil que pode ajudar entender melhor o que está fazendo, o que eu sempre defendo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 17):

Para ser orientado a objeto uma linguagem deve atender aos 4 pilares que são Abstração, Encapsulamento, Herança e Polimorfismo.

Em Java Script podemos aplicar os 4 conceitos facilmente como mostrado abaixo:

**Abstração**
Simplificando é a etapa de modelar um objeto do mundo real com identidade, propriedades e métodos. Isso é feito facilmente com JS:

```
// Define "classe" Pessoa
function Pessoa(nome, idade) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.idade = idade;
}

// Toda pessoa tem uma método fazAniversário
Pessoa.prototype.fazAniversario = function() {
    this.idade++;
}

// Define classe Funcionario
function Funcionario(nome, idade) {
    Pessoa.call(this, nome, idade);
    this.salario = null;
}

// Todo funcionário herda de Pessoa
Funcionario.prototype = Object.create(Pessoa.prototype);

// Teste
var joao = new Funcionario('João', 25);
joao.fazAniversario();
alert(joao.idade); // 26
```

---

**Encapsulamento, Herança e Polimorfismo**

```
// define a classe Person
function Pessoa() {}

Pessoa.prototype.caminhar = function(){
  alert ('Estou Caminhando!');
};
Pessoa.prototype.dizOi = function(){
  alert ('Oi!');
};

// define a classe  Estudante
function Estudante() {
  // Chama o método parente
  Pessoa.call(this);
}

// herda de Pessoa
Estudante.prototype = new Pessoa();

// corrigir o ponteiro construtor porque aponta para Pessoa
Estudante.prototype.constructor = Estudante;

// adiciona o método dizOi
Estudante.prototype.dizOi = function(){
  alert('Oi, eu sou estudante');
}

// adiciona o método dizTchau 
Estudante.prototype.dizTchau = function(){
  alert('tchau');
}

var estudante1 = new Estudante();
estudante1.dizOi();
estudante1.caminhar();
estudante1.dizTchau();

// check inheritance
alert(estudante1 instanceof Pessoa); // true 
alert(estudante1 instanceof Estudante); // true
```

*Utilizando Object.create a linha de herança deveria ser:*

```
Estudante.prototype = Object.create(Pessoa.prototype);
```

No exemplo acima o estudante não precisava saber como o método `walk()` da `classe Pessoa` seria implementada, mas ainda pode utilizar esté método; a `classe Estudante` não possui necessidade explícita de definir o método desde que não queremos alterar-lo. Isso se chama encapsulamento.

---

Apesar de não ser como nas outras linguagem a aplicação dos conceitos de orientação a objeto, JS permite realizar todos eles.
Eu acredito que JS pode sim ser considerada OO.

Espero ter ajudado.

Fontes:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript
http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/
http://tableless.com.br/introducao-a-programacao-orientada-a-objetos-em-javascript/
[Este é um exemplo correto de herança em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7220/este-%C3%A9-um-exemplo-correto-de-heran%C3%A7a-em-javascript)

Answer (score 12):

> Muitos dizem que ela não é uma linguagem Orientada a Objetos, por não
>   ser possível definir classes com ela

1. Existe um objeto chamado [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)
2. `Object` possui uma função chamada [`create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)
3. `create` cria um novo objeto baseado em um objeto pré-existente
4. `Object` possui um objeto chamado [`prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)
5. Todos os objetos são baseados no `Object.prototype`

   - Exceto aqueles criados por `Object.create(null)`

Objetos que possuem objetos criando novos objetos baseados em objetos. O que poderia ser mais orientado a objetos que isso?

Javascript não deixa de ser orientada a objetos só porque outras linguagens confundem o conceito de classes com o paradigma. Classes tem mais a ver com tipagem estática que orientação a objetos.

Afinal, quem disse que é preciso uma "planta" pré-definida para se criar objetos? Javascript não precisa dessa parafernalha. Só precisa de um objeto que cria novos objetos: a função `create`.

> Herança

Podemos criar um objeto baseado em outro. Deste modo, ele herdará as propriedades de sua base:

```
const outro = Object.create(null);
const um = Object.create(outro);

outro.propriedade = 'valor';

um.propriedade;                       // 'valor'
```

> Sobrecarga

Se um objeto possui uma propriedade, ela é usada ao invés da herança:

```
um.propriedade = 'outro valor';

outro.propriedade;                    // 'valor'
um.propriedade;                       // 'outro valor'
```

> Encapsulamento

Objetos possuem propriedades. [É possível configurá-las](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Using_propertiesObject_argument_with_Object.create()) para executar funções `get` e `set`.

Answer (score 11):

Sim, pode ser usado POO no Javascript. Mas assim como no PHP, você pode não usar.

> Programação Orientada a Objetos é um paradigma de programação que usa abstração para criar modelos baseados no mundo real. POO usa várias técnicas vindas de paradigmas previamente estabelecidos, incluindo modularidade, polimorfismo e encapsulamento. Atualmente, muitas linguagens de programação populares (como Java, JavaScript, C #, C ++, Python, PHP, Ruby e Objective-C) permitem a programação orientada a objetos (POO).

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: Ela pode ser usada então quer dizer que ela não é, certo?

Comment: Eu não consigo afirmar se é ou não. Eu **acredito** que não é. Mas é uma das linguagens que permite. Então dá para jogar para o grupo de POG mesmo haha

Comment: Grupo de POG? De "programação orientada a gambiarra"? Enfim, eu sou da escola que diz que JS é suficientemente OO para ser considerada orientada a objetos, não vejo nada ofensivo em afirmar isso. E sua resposta aparentemente contradiz seu comentário, em que você diz que pode usar POO, porém diz que **acredita** não ser orientada a objetos, já que programação orientada a objetos é feita com orientação a objetos...

Comment: **Correção**: Certamente, eu entrei em contradição em meu comentário. Está escrito no Mozilla que é, porém eu não tenho conhecimento de que essa informação é a correta, mas é uma grande influencia. Obrigado