# Herança em programação orientada a objetos

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, herança, composição

Estava lendo [esse artigo](https://imasters.com.br/front-end/javascript/prototipos-no-javascript-parte-01-o-que-sao-prototipos/?trace=1519021197&source=category-archive) hoje e me deparei com a seguinte afirmação:

> *"Herança refere-se a habilidade de um objeto acessar métodos e outras propriedades de outro objeto."*

**Herança** não seria a relação hierárquica entre as classes? Onde elas podem herdar propriedades e métodos de outras classes e assim passá-los para suas instâncias (objetos).

A relação onde objetos acessam propriedades e métodos de outros objetos são descritas nos conceitos de **Associação** (onde um objeto é tido como atributo de outro), **Agregação** (onde um objeto-pai recebe outro objeto em um de seus métodos) e **Composição** (onde um objeto de outra classe é instanciado dentro da própria classe do objeto-pai), certo?

Alguém pode complementar essa afirmação?

Comment: Mostre onde viu isso

Comment: Acredito que isso não é muito relevante pra pergunta, mas vou adicionar o link.

Comment: è, porque se a fonte for um mané escrevendo é uma coisa, se for uma fonte confiável é outra. E o contexto também vai indicar se não é um problema de interpretação.

Comment: Está escrito exatamente como postei na pergunta. :)

Comment: Mas na pergunta não está escrito que fala de protótipos e onde está sendo usado.

Comment: Na introdução do artigo ele fala sobre Herança em POO e não de protótipos: "Em OOP, herança refere-se a habilidade de um objeto acessar métodos e outras propriedades de outro objeto."

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Comment: Não estou falando de classes, você acha que estou porque você acha que isto está relacionado à classes.

Comment: Porque lá fazia sentido falar de classes, por isso que precisa de contexto.

Comment: De qualquer forma, obrigado pela resposta. :)

Comment: Acho que o assunto é muito abrangente para ser tratado por aqui, talvez seria interessante você buscar um livro sobre o tema, existem muitos bons livros por ai.

Comment: De certa forma sim. Já estou aprofundando em POO em livros e cursos.

Answer (score 7):

Já vou começar dizendo o que falo sempre. [Quase ninguém sabe orientação a objeto corretamente, o que me inclui, mas estou fazendo um esforço enorme para resolver as partes pendentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101). E olha que uso isso há cerca de 30 anos.

[Quase todo mundo abusa de herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101). As pessoas acham que [algo tem relação hierárquica quando não tem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101). A maioria dos [objetos são **compostos** por outros objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101) e não são derivados de outros objetos. E praticamente 100% dos exemplos de herança em livros, *blogs*, e outras fontes mostram herança em algo que não tem relação hierárquica (ou que tem mas não é real), o que faz quase todo mundo aprender errado. E a desinformação é disseminada já que as pessoas não são questionadoras.

Nesse caso específico a frase provavelmente foi dita no contexto do JavaScript que não tem a declaração explícita de tipos e sim objetos que servem de [protótipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142884/101) para outros objetos. A frase é infeliz porque dá para interpretar de outra forma. Um objeto acessar propriedade de outro objeto é possível em todo objeto que tenha comportamento, mesmo sem ter relação de herança.

A herança de fato é a relação hierárquica, composta pela capacidade do tipo derivado ter tudo o que o tipo base tem, [seja em implementação (subclasse), seja em contratos (subtipo)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101).

Então um objeto derivado de outro tem as mesmas características do objeto base (seu protótipo), está tudo nele, não tem que acessar outro objeto. A herança se dá por cópia. No novo objeto derivado pode adicionar ou até mesmo mudar certas características (nem todas linguagens permitem isto). Se mudar as características, na minha concepção, acaba com a herança já que o filho não mais é capaz de realizar tudo igual ao pai. No mundo real a herança se manteria, mas no computador se torna complicado. Há quem ache que a herança se mantém.

Note que estamos falando de apenas um objeto, então a palavra "outro" já não cabe aí. Usa-se outro objeto concreto **como modelo** para este objeto, mas acaba a relação entre eles no momento que o novo é criado, não tem que acessar nada no outro. Linguagens totalmente dinâmicas costumam fazer isso.

Em linguagens baseadas em classe funciona do mesmo jeito, só que o modelo é uma planta e não um protótipo, então não há relação com outro objeto nem mesmo no momento da sua criação.

Herança não é sobre classes, esse é mais um erro que quase todo mundo comete. Existe herança sem ter classe. Fora esse ponto a definição do AP está mais correta que do artigo. Classe é uma circunstância da herança.

Isto também nada tem a ver com [Associação, Agregação, Composição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101). Esses são mecanismos poderosos para compor o objeto, mas não há relação direta com acesso, isto é circunstancial.

Estritamente a frase está errada, mas dá para entender o motivo. Claro que para leigos é uma desinformação que colabora para a maioria das pessoas não entenderem o que é OOP, e tudo que as pessoas não entendem, mas acham que entendem, frequentemente passam endeusar aquilo. E tudo que é endeusado "não pode ser contestado" por ela ou outras pessoas. Por isso em programação temos que estudar até teologia :P

Algumas pessoas podem discordar porque há escolas diferentes do que é orientação a objeto. Falei da que parece ser mais usada. Algumas pessoas pegam alguns conceitos de uma escola e outros de outra escola. E chegam até impor conceitos antagônicos na sua concepção. E estou falando de gente que está num patamar profissional acima.

Relacionado: [O que são os conceitos de coesão e acoplamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) (isto é mais importante que OO, o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) também). Veja também: [O que é paradigma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu te daria uma recompensa bem gorda por essa resposta mas você tem mais de 14x a minha reputação :D essa é a melhor resposta que vi este mês.

Comment: @Renan Obrigado. Pena que não vou atingir a mesta de 250 em 2017 :( E não vou dobrar a meta, 2018 só quero melhorar a qualidade do povo, e das minhas respostas que nem sempre estiveram uma maravilha ultimamente (e preciso ver o que ficou pendente :D) . Curiosamente algumas coisas muito interessantes que eu escrevi passaram batido por quase todo mundo.

Comment: As pessoas confudem muito o que é SER algo e TER algo. Você precisa se perguntar isso quando cria classes e relacionamentos, este objeto que você está criando precisar SER de determinado tipo (herdar) ou ele precisa TER acesso a determinado tipo. De qualquer forma como falei acima acho o assunto abrangente demais para tratar nesta plataforma.

Comment: @Zorkind totalmente. Na verdade a maioria das pessoas tem noção próxima de zero disso. Mesmo as que entendem um pouco melhor erram muito na avaliação. Tem muita coisa que parece ser e não é. O exemplo do quadrado e retângulo é o mais emblemático. Alguns casos são debatíveis. Um quadrado **é** uma forma geométrica ou **tem** características de uma forma geométrica? No mundo real eu sei fácil, na abstração do computador isso é um pouco mais complicado :)